# How to calculate elapsed time in seconds in VBA?

Tags: vba, datediff

I have 2 strings, strStartTime and strEndTime.

strStartTime = "12:32:54"
strEndTime = "12:33:05"

I want to find out how many seconds elapsed between strStartTime and strEndTime so I did this:

```
Dim dtDuration as date
dtDuration = DateDiff("s", CDate(strStartTime), CDate(strEndTime))
```

The result I get is dtDuration = "#1/10/1900#" in the Locals watch window.

Why does this happen?  How do I get dtDuration to equal 11 for the 11 seconds that elapsed between the start and end times?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just change variable type to Long:

```
Dim dtDuration as Long
```

VBA converts numerical results of DateDiff functions into variable with date type.